# electron open file dialog

Tags: javascript, electron

trying to open a file in electron to change it's content. but i can't get the open file dialog to work.

this is what i've tried so far:

```
 const { dialog } = require('electron').remote;

document.getElementById("selectBtn").addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    dialog.showOpenDialog({
        properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections']
    }, function (files) {
        if (files !== undefined) {
            console.log(files);

        } else {
            console.log("not working");

        }
    });
});
```

but it really does nothing (except of course opening the dialog)

Comment: What version of Electron are you on? If it's >=6, you need to use the new Promise-based API rather than the old callback one.

Comment: dialog should run on the main process. see the docs > https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialog . easiest way is to send ipc message from render and listen it from main process, then open the dialog and return the selected path back to render